# how to partition my disk after i have installed ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I'm a newbie. I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Vostro 3446.
I want to partition my storage so that after installing a different OS (if I ever need to do it), I don't lose data, similar to a separate partition in Windows for data files (C:\ contains the OS files, and D:\ contains data).

I can't find any satisfactory/clear description on google search on how to do this. I have already read a lot of articles which describe how to do partitioning during installation but i want to partition after installing Ubuntu. A detailed description for this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edited Update**: Screenshot added without output to questions in the comments.
[image]

edited update[image]

Comment: To be clear: You installed Ubuntu as only operating system, you used the default partitioning scheme using the complete hard drive and you now want to add another partion for data? The output of the following commands would be useful: `sudo fdisk -l` (shows the current partioning) and `df -l -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs` (shows the sizes and mount points of all currently mounted local file systems, excluding temporary ones)

Comment: @Adaephon yes,you are right.

Comment: @Adaephon kashish@kashish-Vostro-3446:~$ df -l -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs
Filesystem                  1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 476261416 4993072 447052588   2% /
/dev/sda1                      240972   84986    143545  38% /boot
kashish@kashish-Vostro-3446:~$

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qpeh1jd7oa142y6/Screenshot%20from%202014-10-24%2012%3A40%3A12.png?dl=0

Comment: @Adaephon https://www.dropbox.com/s/jaiwjbskxh826n9/Screenshot%20from%202014-10-24%2012%3A41%3A45.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi @kashish. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Looking at this question, you should click on the question's "edit" button whenever you have useful information to update in the question, although responding to the request with a comment saying something to the effect of "I've updated the question with this information" would be sufficient. As it is, your paste of the df commands in the comment section is very hard to read. Also, don't use dropbox. You can insert screengrabs / screenshots directly into the question. I've updated the question for you this time (although the edit needs peer reviewing).

Comment: @kashish Ok, it seems that you are using LVM on an encrypted partition (/dev/sda5). So using tools like `gparted` is very likely not possible. But, on the plus side, resizing logical volumes (the "partitions" of LVM) is quite easy. Could you add (with [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/540880/edit)) the output of `sudo lvdisplay` and `sudo vgdisplay`, please?

Comment: @Adaephon I've updated the question with this information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use GParted Live to partition your storage.

http://gparted.org/download.php

Comment: yes, i have installed it from software center ,but i dont know how it will work.detailed description is what i need. thank you for your reply.

Comment: You are forced to boot GParted Live from a CD, if you want to partition the storage with the Ubuntu partition.

On Youtube are many great tutorials. Search for "gparted live tutorial".

Comment: thank you.i will look for that. meanwhile tell me that https://www.dropbox.com/s/gc68py0ewx84qop/Screenshot%20from%202014-10-24%2013%3A01%3A58.png?dl=0.  what does "create as primary partition" and align to mib mean and where will they be created?

Comment: Why GParted Live and not standard Ubuntu Live (which has GParted installed)?

Comment: Ubuntu Live with Gparted would work, too. But it's more easy to use a simple Gparted Live since you have lots of other disc tools in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GParted for this. But you cannot tamper the partition on which the ubuntu is running. That means you need to boot from a live cd. Use a live cd or create bootable pendrive using lili. And boot from it. Then using GParted, you can edit the partitions. Feel free to delete create or shrink partition, but be carefull when you hit the apply button. Hope it helps.